# Matrix values are inf/nan in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I am attempting to use polynomial regression on a set of points to map them to a curve. When I am constructing the design matrix, the assignment values don't seem to be going through properly. The matrix constructed is a 3 x n matrix where n is the number of points and, as is in with a design matrix, the first column should be all 1's (From the `// HERE IS ASSIGNMENT` section). When I print the matrix, the first column is full of random numbers and very often, infs and nans. How is that possible for constant assignment? This then causes further problems with doing any math with the matrix since it is full of not numbers and infs.

The code below is where the matrix is being constructed.

```
for (auto it = lane_lines.begin(); it != lane_lines.end(); it++) {
                        vector<pair<Point, Point> > lines = *it;

                        // Remove random line clusters
                        if (lines.size() < 10) {
                                it = --lane_lines.erase(it);
                                continue;
                        }   

                        Mat design(lines.size() * 2, 3, CV_64FC1);
                        Mat y_vec(lines.size() * 2, 1, CV_64FC1);

                        for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 2) {
                                // HERE IS ASSIGNMENT
                                design.at<double>(i * 2, 0) = 1.0;
                                design.at<double>(i * 2, 1) = lines[i].first.x;
                                design.at<double>(i * 2, 2) = pow(lines[i].first.x, 2); 
                                design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 0) = 1.0;
                                design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 1) = lines[i].second.x;
                                design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 2) = pow(lines[i].second.x, 2); 

                                y_vec.at<double>(i * 2, 0) = lines[i].first.y;
                                y_vec.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 0) = lines[i].second.y;
                        }   

                        // TODO: Deal with all the NaNs
                        cout << design << endl;
                        cout << design.t() * design << endl;
                        cout << "DET: " << determinant(design.t() * design) << endl << endl;

                        Mat std_poly = ((design.t() * design).inv() * design.t()) * y_vec;

                        double a = std_poly.at<double>(0, 2); 
                        double b = std_poly.at<double>(0, 1); 
                        double c = std_poly.at<double>(0, 0); 
                        double h = -b / (2 * a == 0 ? numeric_limits<double>::min() : 2 * a); 
                        double k = c - (a * pow(h, 2));

                        tuple<double, double, double, Point> curve(a, b, c, Point(h, k));
                        curves.push_back(curve);
                }
```

Edit: The problem occurs, seemingly, randomly for different data sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A first look at your code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); i += 2) {
     // HERE IS ASSIGNMENT
     design.at<double>(i * 2, 0) = 1.0;
     design.at<double>(i * 2, 1) = lines[i].first.x;
     design.at<double>(i * 2, 2) = pow(lines[i].first.x, 2); 
     design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 0) = 1.0;
     design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 1) = lines[i].second.x;
     design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 2) = pow(lines[i].second.x, 2); 
     y_vec.at<double>(i * 2, 0) = lines[i].first.y;
     y_vec.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 0) = lines[i].second.y;
   }
```

For the first iteration `i=0` those two lines

```
design.at<double>(i * 2, 0) = 1.0;
design.at<double>(i * 2 + 1, 0) = 1.0;
```

become:

```
design.at<double>(0, 0) = 1.0;
design.at<double>(1, 0) = 1.0;
```

Then next iteration is `i=2` because of `i+=2` in loop so the above lines become:

```
design.at<double>(4, 0) = 1.0;
design.at<double>(5, 0) = 1.0;
```

I think you should change `i+=2` to `i++` to fix the behavior.

**NB** Your code may have other problems.

Comment: Oh man, I am a fool. I had that += 2 for an older version where the data structure was different but I forgot to change it when I shifted my code base. Thank you.

Comment: @DSchana it happens for all of us. But remember to always debug your program.